# Possible to playback RFID card using NFC functionality on phone?

Tags: security, nfc

Sometimes I forget my RFID door access card at home when I go to work, and when this happens I must stay in the building for the rest of the day or have a friend let me in if I leave during the day (i.e. to go to lunch).

My Galaxy S4 phone has NFC capability.  Is it possible to record my RFID door access card to my phone so I can use my phone in lieu of my card for times when I forget my card?

I have not found any apps which will do this, so I am wondering if the phone is even capable of performing this function.

Comment: I doubt it. Especially since there are several *types* of RFID implementations. [MIFARE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mifare) alone has several variants.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg multiple applications exist in Google Play to read and write RFID cards.  I would be surprised to learn the NFC functionality can read and write RFID but not play it back.

Comment: @steampowered - Have you tried those applications?  There are so many things they could do to make the RFID difficult to clone.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the RFID system you are talking about only expects a key, and then does a look up in the user db.

Usually, a new UID is generated for each NFC transaction by phones.
Some users have been able to maintain a static UID sent from the phone to the RFID receiver.  A static UID will then act to send a constant "key" across to the RFID receiver instead of a generated one, everytime you try to swipe the device.

To obtain the static UID, you need to change the firmware on your phone, to only send one UID. Users on [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=40581257) forum have achieved it on the Google Nexus S and EVO 4g LTE.

Happy days!

Comment: I was definitely assuming the state of the RFID card does not change from one swipe to another.  Interesting - I never thought about the possibly that the RFID card was storing a token or some other data for the next swipe.  I also never considered the phone changing the UID for each transaction.  Interesting thread you posted - I will let you know the results of my tests tomorrow when I bring my card to work.

Answer (score 6):

You can melt the card with acetone, which will get you the chip and antenna. You could then stick them inside your phone cover and use it as an RFID card.

Comment: That's certainly a great idea if you have to return the card at some point and nothing is left of it.

Comment: In that case I will tell them that I lost it.... $4 max.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your access-control system. Normally, the UID of the card is not used in access control, but rather encrypted information on the card. Therefore, it is not possible to clone/record your RFID card.

Comment: There is a message being sent to the card reader.  Assuming that message doesn't change, I should be able to play it back.  Am I missing something?

Comment: 1. not only 1 message, there are protocolls for comunication between reader and card, depending on the card type.

Comment: 2. for example if you have an mifare Desfire card, the relevant information (something like an access control number) is send encrypted to the reader. According to the protocol reader and card 'generate' an session key for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use the NFC (Near Field Communication) functionality on a phone to emulate or simulate the behavior of an RFID (Radio Frequency Identification) card. NFC is a technology that allows for short-range wireless communication between devices, and it is commonly found in many smartphones.

By leveraging the NFC capabilities of a phone, it is feasible to replicate certain functionalities of an RFID card. However, the success and ease of this process depend on several factors, such as the specific NFC chipset and software capabilities of the phone, the compatibility with the targeted RFID system, and the security measures implemented by the RFID system itself. In some cases, additional software or apps may be required to configure the phone's NFC behavior to emulate the desired RFID card in any wearables such as an [RFID wristband](https://www.embedcard.com/hardware-solutions/mobilewallet). It's important to note that the legality and ethical implications of such actions may vary depending on the specific context and purpose for which the emulation is being used.

Comment: -1 Clearly LLM-generated and doesn't actually address the real question, either: How?